# Why Nexus renames my artifacts?

Tags: maven, gradle, nexus

Hello I have module with name desc-editor, and it is contains submodules:

1. desc-editor-server
2. desc-editor-vaadin
3. desc-editor-local

I'm using Gradle 1.8. When I execute gradle install it makes folders with jars in local maven repository with names I provider above. But when I make upload to Nexus repo it renames artifacts to server, vaadin and local respectively.

Comment: because Nexus put the files under the artefact name

Comment: But Nexus does not change the artifactId, does it?

Comment: @JFMeier it does, I looked into metadata.xml

Comment: Check your gradle logs (run at debug if needed), Nexus doesn't rename anything, whatever is showing up in Nexus is what is being put there by Gradle.